# XML and XSL data extraction?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to extract data from xml file that is on a particular path/destination using document function of xsl. i had tried this one but it is not working. `<xsl:variable name="fi" select="document('C:/folder/Results.xml')"/>

            <b><xsl:value-of select="$fi/Report/Doc/DName"/></b>`

Comment: Pls. change it to document('file:/C:/folder/Results.xml') and revert back

Comment: Also tell us more about the environment you are trying to use XSLT in, as using the `document` function might need to be enabled explicitly or as accessing the file system (from the browser) is not allowed.

Comment: Actually i m using Unified Functional Testing(OLD name was QTP .HP s/w) for automation .This tool have a feature to add XSL to generate Report in HTML form. If know about UFT Than Tools->Options->General->Run Session ->Automatically export Run Result when Run Session End ->Configure User Defined XSL.                     UFT generate an XML file and a user defined XSl extract data from that xml file and put extracted data to HTML file.i need to add a specific path for XML in XSL file and want to include/add XSL to UFT    Option.Document function is not working in this si.tuation. plz help me.